# Change Identity from an existing database with a foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I've made 2 mistakes and I really don't know how to solve it. At first I've insert an object in my table and the identity is not the good one. It should be 1 instead of 10

[image: I've create only one person and it the identity start at 10, I really dont know why and I need to fix it to 1]

[image: In the column property I see that the identity is set to 1,1]

My second mistake is that I've set some identity in my tables to 1,1 instead of 10,10. But since both of my mistakes are foreign key I really don't know how fix this.

Thank you.

P.S I would like to know how to change these Identity without having to change it in every other tables since it's a foreign key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're the first who has decided to change things like this with foreign keys etc.

My usual approach is very manual but tends to work. I like having a lot of manual oversight of these sorts of situations rather than writing complex code and hoping it works.

For the demonstration below, I'm assuming table T1 has a foreign key link to table T2 (e.g., table T1 has a field T2_Id).

The main issue is that you cannot just change the value in T2 (e.g., from 1 to 10) because it doesn't exist in table T2. The second issue is the possibility that the desired ID already exists in your table.

Therefore, the broad approach I take is to

1. Copy the row in T2 from the original ID to the new ID
2. Update the relevant row in T1 to refer to the new T2_Id
3. Delete the original row from T2

Notes

- Do these changes in a try-catch and transaction in case anything goes wrong
- I find that creating a temporary table first with T2_ID_old and T2_ID_new is useful
- You'll need to `SET IDENTITY INSERT T2 ON;` before doing the insert to T2, follow it with `SET IDENTITY INSERT T2 OFF;`
- If values that you want already exist, then you'll probably need to do loops. The simplest (though slowest) loop is do them 1 at a time, and (if you're changing the values upwards) start with the maximum value first (to clear the spot for later updates)

Broad example of code with the 1-line-at-a-time loop. Feel free to update it. Feel free to use a CURSOR too instead of a WHILE loop.

```
DECLARE @CurrentT2IdOriginal int
DECLARE @CurrentT2IdNew int

SET @CurrentT2IdOriginal = (SELECT TOP 1 T2_ID_Original FROM #T2_Updates ORDER BY T2_ID_original DESC)

WHILE @CurrentT2IdOriginal IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN

    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION

        SET @CurrentT2IDNew = (SELECT TOP 1 T2_ID_New FROM #T2_Updates WHERE T2_ID_original = @CurrentT2IdOriginal)

        SET IDENTITY_INSERT T2 ON;
        INSERT INTO T2 (ID, randomtext)
            SELECT  @CurrentT2IdNew, randomtext
            FROM    T2
            WHERE   T2.ID = @CurrentT2IdOriginal
        SET IDENTITY_INSERT T2 OFF;

        UPDATE T1 SET T2_ID = @CurrentT2IdNew WHERE T2_ID = @CurrentT2IdOriginal

        DELETE FROM T2 WHERE Id = @CurrentT2IdOriginal

        SET @CurrentT2IdOriginal = (SELECT TOP 1 T2_ID_Original FROM #T2_Updates WHERE T2_ID_Original < @CurrentT2IdOriginal ORDER BY T2_ID_original DESC)

        COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        THROW;
    END CATCH

    END
```

Here's a [DB<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=009f015f04d7574146cf72d7164d80e8) with full example

Note - at some point in the process you will also need to change the ID field from identity(1,1) to identity(10,10).

**Important**

- Do this on a test site first.
- Review your data afterwards in case someone has inserted more rows while you're doing this.